# Voice recorder for Android with marker support

Tags: android, voice-recording

I'm looking for a voice recorder to be used on one of my Android devices.

#### Requirements (must-have)

- works on Android 6+
- lets me set the desired recording quality (a discussion must not be recorded HiFi – but a music session probably should)
- lets me set markers *while recording* (think of chapters in an eBook, or a topic switch in a meeting). Playback being capable to "jump to" markers.
- must be free
- must be privacy-friendly (as much as possible; in the best case, it will only require permissions to access the mike and the storage)
- low battery use (so I can have it running multiple hours without a break)
- support "long recording sessions" (it's OK if it starts a new file e.g. every hour); a 6h limit would be OK
- Recording in background (even when display is off)
- playback capabilities (to listen into my recordings)
- should be simple and easy to use (so no "overblown" GUI)
- "small and handsome" (`.apk` shouldn't be tens of megabytes in size)

#### Nice-to-Have

- FOSS (free as in "free speech" *and* as in "free beer")
- availability on F-Droid
- visual "gain control" (so I can e.g. see whether the speaker will be heard in the recording)
- tagging of recordings (e.g. "speeches", "meetings", "business", "personal" …)
- simple edit functionality (to e.g. cut off from the start or the end of an recording, or to split a file)
- date-and-time stamping (if that's possible, e.g. via Metadata). Playback being capable to "jump to" timestamps.
- option to "skip silence" (i.e. only record if there's sound)
- also works on Kitkat (yes, I have some older devices which could serve as "dedicated voice recorder")
- still being actively maintained would be appreciated

#### Definitely NOT needed/wanted

- cloud storage (Dropbox, GDrive, whatever)
- tons of trackers and ad modules
- unrelated "Gimmicks"

I've already checked related questions, and they do not match my needs:

- [Voice recorder for Android](/q/16408/185): None of my requirements, but only "should be invisible while running" – which again isn't one of my requirements
- [Specialized audio recorder for Android](/q/23261/185): Meets my requirements on "low battery use" and "long recording sessions" (and one answer also covers the recording quality) – but not the others
- [Android voice recorder that will allow me to save to dropbox](/q/21071/185): Contradicts with my requirements
- [Voice recording while taking note](/q/26096/185): Not covering my requirements (except for time stamping)

Comment: Just adding some notes, as I've only found those apps now but haven't tried them yet. Coming pretty close at least are [Canomapp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ffdrop.canoma) and [Meeting Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meetings.recorder). If anyone uses one of them, an answer would be welcome (even if it wouldn't fit *all* requirements, the app might be helpful to others or be a fallback for me if nothing better was turning up).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the app **Recordense Voice Recorder** meets all of your requirements (except battery usage which I don't know, but with the screen off I doubt it will suck much battery.)

Even let's you add tags from the lock screen notification directly.

Has a free version with some limitations (the worst of which is only 3 tags per recording https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ls.iris.apps.recorder.light (the pro version is only $3.35)

Comment: Looks very promising indeed, thanks (and +1) – but contains Admob and Flurry in both, the free and the paid version. OK, I wrote "tons of trackers" as no-go, and this is "just 2 of them" :) And an added plus: Pebble support. Hm. Take it for Pebble or leave it for trackers? You brought me into trouble now :D Unfortunately, the Pro version uses Google License Check and thus is unlikely to work on Google-free devices :(